# Need a concise way to query a database with limited filters

Tags: data-analysis, searching

I have two observers identifying pets - Sam and Cindy. For each pet, Sam and Cindy have to say what kind of pet they see (dog, cat, leprechaun, etc.). They enter their results into a database and I need to confirm the quality of their work. The first thing I want to do is see when Sam and Cindy disagreed on what kind of pet they saw.

This sounds easy enough but there are a few challenges. Firstly, there are thousands of records, so I'm not able to check the results manually. I need to query the database they entered their results into.

This is how the database works:

1. I can only use 20 filters or less in a single query
2. An individual filter can only check Sam or Cindy's results
3. The filter can compare their results to a specific value (e.g. Sam's answer matches 'dog')
4. The filter can check multiple values (e.g. Sam's answer matches 'dog' or 'cat' or 'mouse')
5. A filter can match or not match on all values (e.g. Sam's answer *does not match* 'dog')
6. Filters combine with AND/OR operators (e.g. Sam matches 'dog' AND Cindy does not match 'dog')
7. Once the query is run I will see all records that return TRUE against the filters
8. Cindy and Sam were able to pick from the same 42 pets for all their answers
9. I can only do one query

Here are three example queries:

1. Sam matches 'dog' and Cindy does not match 'dog' gets me 1/42nd of the way to the answer I want
2. (Sam matches 'dog' and Cindy does not match 'dog') OR (Sam matches 'cat' and Cindy does not match 'cat')
3. (Sam matches 'dog' or 'cat' or 'stone') AND (Cindy does not match 'dog' or 'cat' or 'stone')

I can use the second example to cover all 42 possible values but this would require 84 filters and I only have 20.

The way I've used the third example is technically within the rules but it doesn't get the right result because it won't show me records where Sam said dog and Cindy said cat even though this is something I would want to flag as a mistake.

Is there a clever way I can expand on the 3rd example (using OR operators within a filter) to get the end result I'm after in 20 filters or less?

If not, what's the most efficient I can get to be able to do this operation in the fewest number of queries.

Comment: Using your example query #2, would you say you used 2 filters or 7 filters?

Comment: @vvg - example 2 is using 4 filters. Each time we check one of Sam or Cindy's values we are using a filter so '"Sam matches 'dog'" is one filter.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming every bold clause in the query below is a filter.

If you run

> (Sam **matches** 'x' **and** Cindy **matches** 'x')
>
> **or** (Sam **matches** 'x' **and** Cindy **does not match** 'x')
>
> **or** (Sam **does not match** 'x' **and** Cindy **matches** 'x')
>
> **or** (Sam **does not match** 'x' **and** Cindy **does not match** 'x')

then we would have used a total of $15$ filters. This compound query is a tautology (i.e., always true) and every record in the database will satisfy this compound query. We don't care what the value of 'x' is (i.e., it could be 'dog', 'cat' or any valid attribute value).

It works on the principle that if we have two clauses $x, y$ then $(x \land y) \lor (x \land y') \lor (x' \land y) \lor (x' \land y')$ is always true.

You mention:

> I want to ... see when Sam and Cindy disagreed on what kind of pet
> they saw

This is a classic XOR operation. ie., if $x,y$ are two clauses and we want when they are complements of each other, we write

$$x \oplus y \Leftrightarrow (x \land y') \lor (x' \land y)$$. The equivalent query for a single choice 'x' would be

> (Sam **matches** 'x' **and** Cindy **does not match** 'x')
>
> **or** (Sam **does not match** 'x' **and** Cindy **matches** 'x')

This uses $7$ filters and gives only results where there is a mismatch between Sam and Cindy for a specific choice 'x'.

If you run a slight modification of the first query

> (Sam **matches** 'x' **and** Cindy **does not match** 'x')
>
> **or** (Sam **does not match** 'x' **and** Cindy **matches** 'x')
>
> **or** (Sam **does not match** 'x' and Cindy **does not match** 'x')

where 'x' is say 'cat' then you will get a few false positives e.g. Sam chooses 'dog' and Cindy chooses 'dog' (and any choice that is not 'cat' where they agree). This uses 10 filters.

Comment: Thanks for this. The challenge is that I need to do this for all 42 possible values in one go while using fewer than 20 filters. So I would need to times the number of filters you used for 1 value by 42.

I don't believe it's possible to do it for the values one by one which is why I was wondering whether it can be done by using multiple values in a single filter (e.g. Sam matches 'x, y, z').

Comment: No. You will get all values where the two observers differ. So, a single query will return all diffs. 'x' can be any value for eg: 'cat'. The first conjuction will get all Sam's choices that are 'cat's and the second conjunction will get all Sam's choices that are not 'cat's. The Cindy condition checks for the differences from Sam's choices. So, you get all rows that are mismatches.

Comment: Ok. If I translate this to the pet analogy I get the following: (Sam matches 'dog' and Cindy does not match 'dog') OR (Sam does not match 'dog' and Cindy matches 'dog'). Is that correct? I don't see how that will find examples where Cindy put 'cat' and Sam put 'hamster'. I want all mismatches across any of the possible values in one query.

Comment: Yes. You are correct. I have given a third option. It returns some false positives which may have to be manually reviewed. But it uses only 10 filters. If you know which choice is most prolific, you should use 'x' as that choice to minimize the false positives that need to be manually looked at.

Comment: Thanks. Just tested and it now returned all entries aside from ones with 'x, x'. Using pairs to describe Sam and Cindy's results: if the database contains 'x, x', 'x, y', 'y, y', 'y, z', 'z, a', 'a, a'' then I want the query to return 'x, y', 'y, z', and 'z, a'. It has to find mismatched examples that don't include an 'x' but not include non-x matches (e.g. 'y, y' or 'z, z').